# Cannot delete database in Mongo: it returns immediately (and mysteriously) after we delete it

Tags: mongodb

when we run the `show dbs` command, the `x-development` database doesn't appear. then when we drop the database from the shell, it still allows us to access it again:

```
> use x-development
switched to db x-development
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "x-development", "ok" : 1 }
> use x-development
switched to db x-development
>
```

why is this happening? we're on mongo 2.2.

we're trying to drop the database because it appears under `mongostat`, and we want to make sure this database isn't taking server resources:

```
[root@mongo]# mongostat
connected to: 127.0.0.1
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults               locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time
     0      5      0      0       0       1       1  2.11g  4.86g   464m      0 x-development:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0    62b     2k     3   11:42:57
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  2.11g  4.86g   464m      0 x-development:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0    62b     2k     3   11:42:58
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  2.11g  4.86g   464m      0 x-development:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0    62b     2k     3   11:42:59
```

so the real question is: why is this database appearing under `mongostat` if the database doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> db.dropDatabase()
```

...indeed drops the database. `use` can switch to any database, existing or not, it's not until you actually insert something that the database is recreated.

> > show dbs
>   local (empty)
>
> > use dev
>   switched to db dev
>
> > show dbs
>   local (empty)
>
> > db.test.insert({a:1})
>
> > show dbs
>   dev   0.203125GB
>   local (empty)
>
> > db.dropDatabase()
>   { "dropped" : "dev", "ok" : 1 }
>
> > show dbs
>   local (empty)

Comment: @Crashalot You may be able to get a better answer on _why_ `mongostat` shows a deleted database than this, but I managed to repeat the effect and a mongod restart removed it from the stats.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongo you don't create databases explicitly. You just start using it (for example by issuing a `use` statement) and it gets created automatically.

The database won't be using any resources if you don't query it. So, I don't think you should worry about it.

Comment: I don't think you chould care. The only way a database can be taking resources is processing queries. You don't query it—it doesn't use any resources.